# Dashboard layout with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

First of all please let me say that I'm not a frontend dev :)

Below is a screenshot of the dashboard I'm working on:

[image]

And here's the markup:

```
<div className="flex flex-col h-full bg-pink-600">
  <div className="h-14 grid content-center bg-green-500">Top</div>
  <div className="flex bg-yellow-500 h-full">
    <div className="w-14 grid justify-center p-3 bg-red-800">L</div>
    <div className="flex-1 p-10 no-scrollbar bg-blue-800 border border-red-500">
      <div className="h-full flex flex-col-3 flex-wrap content-start gap-5 bg-pink-200">
        <Item />
        <Item />
        <Item />
        <Item />
        <Item />
        <Item />
        <Item />
        <Item />
        <Item />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className="h-12 grid ml-1 content-center bg-green-500">Status</div>
</div>
```

All fine so far but when I increase the number of items, the container for the items also expand vertically, leading to this output:

[image]

So basically, what I need is a scrollable container (the pink-colored div) that doesn't expand, and without the scrollbars but couldn't sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up messing around with flex and used this:

```
<div className="absolute top-0 right-0 bottom-0 left-0">
  <div className="absolute left-0 w-14 top-0 h-14 w-full border-8 border-red-500 bg-blue-500">Top</div>
  <div className="absolute top-14 left-0 w-14 bottom-0 border-8 border-blue-500 bg-green-500">Status</div>
  <div className="absolute top-14 left-14 bottom-0 right-0 flex flex-col-3 flex-wrap overflow-scroll no-scrollbar gap-5 border-8 border-yellow-500 bg-green-500">
    <Item />
    .....
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow-scroll` to the styles of your pink container div.

Comment: Doesn't work. This just adds an additional scrollbar inside the pink div and the one inside the blue div is still there.